# Sorting Data and printing into a file

Tags: python, file, sorting

I have five functions i) lab average ii) program_average iii) midterm_average iv) final and v) weighted_total_score

How do i create a new function that will sort data based on one of the options above and write it into a file of the users choice?

My code so far is rather repetitive. Is there a way I can condense this?

```
def sorted_data(student_name):

    print("This option is for sorting students data and printing in a file")
    print("(i) lab average, (ii) program average, (iii) midterm average, (iv) final, (v) weighted total score")
    user_sorted_data=(input("Select one of the options (i-v):"))
    write_sorted_file=print(input("What file would you like this written into?"))

    if (user_sorted_data=='i'):
        print("You have selected sorting student data upon lab average")
        f=open('write_sorted_file','w')
        f.write (str(student_lab_average(student_scores)))
        f.close()

    if (user_sorted_data=='ii'):
        print("You have selected sorting student data upon program average")
        f=open('write_sorted_file','w')
        f.write (str(student_prog_average(student_scores)))
        f.close()

    if (user_sorted_data=='iii'):
        print("You have selected sorting student data upon midterm average")
        f=open('write_sorted_file','w')
        f.write (str(mid_average(student_scores)))
        f.close()

    if (user_sorted_data=='iv'):
        print("You have selected sorting student data upon the final grade")
        f=open('write_sorted_file','w')
        f.write (str(overall_grade(student_scores)))
        f.close()

    if (user_sorted_data=='v'):
        print("You have selected sorting student data upon weighted total score")
        f=open('write_sorted_file','w')
        f.write (str(weighted_total_score(student_scores)))
        f.close()
```

I am calling the function like so

```
elif(ch== 'e'):
    print(" ")
    student_name=input("Type the student's last name:")
    print(" ")
    scores= get_data_for_student(student_name,mid1,mid2,final,homework,labs,program1,program2,program3,participation)
    f=open('write_sorted_file', 'w')
    print(" ")
    f.write("Here are all the numbers in the text file sorted.") +    str(sorted_data(scores))
    f.close()
```

Comment: Use a dict - small code snippet here. Note there are no quotes around function names.
`funcmap = {'i':student_lab_average, 'ii':student_prog_average, ...}`
Then say `f.write(str(funcmap[user_sorted_data](student_scores)))`

Comment: Where is this function asking for the file to write into ? @minocha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as small as I can condense,

```
options_functions = {'i':student_lab_average,
       'ii':student_prog_average,
       'iii':overall_grade,
       'iv': overall_grade,
       'v':weighted_total_score
                 }
options_strings = {'i':'lab average',
       'ii':'program average',
       'iii':'midterm average',
       'iv': 'final grade',
       'v':'weighted total score'
                 }

def sorted_data(student_scores):

    print("This option is for sorting students data and printing in a file")
    print("(i) lab average, (ii) program average, (iii) midterm average, (iv) final, (v) weighted total score")

    user_sorted_data=input("Select one of the options (i-v):")

    write_sorted_file=input("What file would you like this written into?")

    print("You have selected sorting student data upon "+options_strings[user_sorted_data])
    f=open('write_sorted_file','w')
    f.write(str(options_functions[user_sorted_data](student_scores)))
    f.close()
```

Edit:

The variable names are not the same.

You are using `student_name` as local variable name when defining your function to which you are passing scores. change that to 'student_scores'.

`student_scores` variable doesn't exist either globally or locally so its raising error `student_scores` not defined

and there is an error at this line

`f.write("Here are all the numbers in the text file sorted.") +    str(sorted_data(scores))`

function `sorted_data` is not returning anything. It returns `None`

you can't add function and a string

Put `f.write("Here are all the numbers in the text file sorted.")` inside `sorted_data` as you are writing to a file inside sorted_data or open it as `append`, if you open it as `write` it  will replace all previous data

Comment: Would you have an idea of why i am getting an error when executing function, saying "student_scores not defined" @Harwee

Comment: well I assumed that student_scores is a variable "most commonly a list" containing scores of student and passed to functions to get sorted data as result. replace student_scored with whatever the input to the functions. and this is assuming that all functions have similar type of input

Comment: i think student_name must be used in place of student_scores, that is much more convenient to use and define individual functions to process and return data based on student name

Comment: Could it be how i am calling the function in the main menu ? @Harwee i will edit question to include this part

Comment: We BOTH assumed that you would be returning a list of integers from the functions called. Also, trying intialising student_scores properly.

Comment: This code seems to be working. It is saying that the file has been written but I cannot see where the file has been written. For some reason it isn't saving. @Harwee

Comment: It is saved in the same folder from where you are executing the code and it doesn't have an extension so it will be just a file

Comment: @Harwee I have made those changes and my function is saving as a file called write_sorted_file writing "none"

Answer (score 1):

Python lists have a built-in `list.sort()` method that modifies the list in-place. There is also a sorted() built-in function that builds a new sorted list from an iterable. So, assuming each method(lab_average,prog_average,etc) returns a list of integers,you could condense it very easily by calling `sort()` and opening and closing the file just once.

```
 with open('write_sorted_file','w') as f:

    if (user_sorted_data=='i'):

        print("You have selected sorting student data upon lab average")
        arr_of_int = student_lab_average(student_scores)
        f.write (str(arr_of_int.sort()))

    #other if statements

    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see following lines repeated in your code:

```
print("You have selected sorting student data upon lab average")



f=open('write_sorted_file','w')

f.write (str(student_lab_average(student_scores)))

f.close()
```

You can wrap these lines into a function like the following

```
def writeToSortedFile(sortFunction, message)
    print(message)

    f=open('write_sorted_file','w')

    f.write (str(sortedFunction(student_scores)))

    f.close()
```

The above code just removes the code repetition.  You can call `writeToSortedFile` after each `if` statements.